# Cannot get exif imagetype data on specific jpeg image

Tags: php, exif, getimagesize

I have a .jpg image (cjonline.com/sites/default/files/13183951.jpg) from a specific url that I cannot get the image size for because it will not process the exif data or getimagesize functions. I am able to get data for all other .jpg images just fine and I can't seem to understand why this one keeps failing. It loads fine in a browser.

```
$image = 'http://cjonline.com/sites/default/files/13183951.jpg';
try {
if ($image !== '') {

    // Gets image width and length
    switch (@exif_imagetype($image))
    {
        case 1:   //   gif -> jpg
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        break;

        case 2:   //   jpeg -> jpg
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        break;

        case 3:  //   png -> jpg
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        break;

        default:
        $img = '';
        return array(0,0);
    }
    $imgWidth = imagesx($img);
    $imgHeight = imagesy($img);
}
}
catch(Exception $e) { $img = ''; }
return array($imgWidth, $imgHeight);
```

Comment: Not all image files have exif data.

Comment: So is there any way to get image size data for images that don't have exif data?

Comment: Yes.  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_file);

Comment: getimagesize doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can get size with this:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_file);
```

Comment: getimagesize does not work either. I get: PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://cjonline.com/sites/default/files/13183951.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden